# Could not download transform-api.jar

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After trying to compile my first Android Studio 3.1.1, this is the only error I get. I wonder what it means because I cannot seem to debug it?

> projectError:Could not download transform-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api): No cached version available for offline mode"

Answer (score 9):

Uncheck the `offline work` and syn the project again.

[image]